# Filtering results of a foreach... PHP

Tags: php, foreach

I currently have a list of items that are stored in a database that are retrieved and displayed using a foreach.

```
foreach($files as $file){
echo'<div class="col-lg-9" id="file-'.$file['id'].'">
        <div class="file-list-item first" id="">
            <img class="file-image" height="120px" width="180px" src="'.$file['image_url'].'" />
            <div class="file-text">
                <h3><strong>'.$file['name'].'</strong></h3>
                Submitted by: '.$file['submitter'].'<br/>
                Author: '.$file['author'].'<br />
                Category: '.ucfirst($file['subcategory']).'<br />
                Description: '.substr($file['description'],0,45).'...
            </div>
            <div class="download">
                <a target="_blank" href="'.$file['download_url'].'" class="btn-success btn btn-default">Download</a>
                <a href="'.baseurl.'/broken.php?id='.$file['id'].'" class="btn btn-default">Report as Broken</a><br /><br />';
                    if($file['is_broken']){
                        echo '<span class="broken"><i data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" id="broken" title="This file has been reported as broken and is awaiting review." class="fa fa-warning fa-2x"></i></span>';
                    }


                echo '

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';
};
```

What would be the best way to filter these results using a drop down menu?
The value I wish to filter by is `$file['subcategory']

So, I wish for various categories to be displayed in a dropdown menu, and once the value of this is changed, I wish for the page to refresh and display only the results the user desires.

Many thanks.

Comment: We don't see how your $files variable is filled initially. Generally, the solution is; add a dropdown to your page, post it to the server, and use the posted value to filter the way the $files array is filled with file info.

Comment: If you expect to have a lot of returned values, you may want to consider having your database do this filtering rather than PHP. If you're refreshing the page and a PHP script is going to run, you're likely going to retrieve the results again anyway, right?  Filtering at the database level is part of what makes your database powerful.

Comment: @MitchGoshorn, Thankyou ever so much, you got my mind rolling on this and I've just implemented the filtering as database level. It's perfect!

Comment: Also, how difficult would it be to implement a "refine by title" where people can enter a search term?

Comment: This may be a topic for a new question, but this really depends on how in depth you want it. If you expect multiple words in your string, you could explode the string and use foreach to add each word into your query, as in `SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%term1%' AND title LIKE '%term2%';` Careful use of `AND`, `OR`, `_` and `%` could help better your results. Regular expressions are also a great option if you're comfortable with them.